# jQuery cookies : change body id while page loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, javascript

How can we change body ID while page loading?

I have just developed an application to change body id which working fine. I would like to detect body ID while page loading which I have chose already.

Here is the code for making cookies, it is working fine

```
$("#line_view").click(function(){
    $("#box_lev").attr('id','horiz_lev');       
    $.cookie("view_method","horiz_lev", {expires: 365, path: '/'});
});
$("#box_view").click(function(){
    $("#horiz_lev").attr('id','box_lev');
    $.cookie("view_method","box_lev", {expires: 365, path: '/'});
    $("#open").trigger('click');
});
```

I would to add id while page loading.

Here's my wrong code for that:

```
if($.cookie("view_method")){
     $("body").attr('id',$.cookie("view_method"));      
}
```

Comment: so what's wrong here? doesn't it work?

Comment: @Joseph unfortunately no :( 
here is my HTML code `<body id="box_lev">` this is permanent code. I need to change if cookies class available

Comment: have you checked the debugger if that code was actually fired during load?

Comment: @Joseph just add this code `alert( $.cookie("view_method") );` it show exact data from cookies. 
I don't know about debugger. Could you tell tell me that please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your cookie does have a value, and you just want to trigger it on page load, try this:

```
$(function(){
    if($.cookie("view_method")){
        $("body").attr('id',$.cookie("view_method"));      
    }
});
```